# How can I initialize a new object inside a construction function so that each of its function can reuse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

```
function x() {
  var obj1 = new ErrorPrinter();
} 
x.prototype = {
 xFunction1 : function() {
    return obj1.printthis("x");
 },

 xFunction2 : function() {
    return obj1.printthis("y");
 }
}
```

But when I do the above, it wont work. The whole purpose of initializing the object on top is the so that I don't have to recreate the same object in each function(xFunction1 and xFunction2).

Thx for such a wonderful community, stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable as you did will only make it available inside the constructor function itself, not other functions on the prototype.

On the other hand, if you were to set `this.obj1 = ...` in the constructor, it would be available as `this.obj1` in the other prototype methods when they are called on an instance.

```
function X() {
  this.obj1 = new ErrorPrinter();
} 
X.prototype = {
  xFunction1: function() {
    return this.obj1.printthis("x");
  },

  xFunction2: function() {
    return this.obj1.printthis("y");
  }
};
```